# Can we declare a variable of type cufftComplex in side a kernel

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I'm using CUFFT library in my code.

```
__global__ void kernel1(...)
{
    /****** processing to get real and imaginary values *******/
    cufftComplex data[SIGANAL_SIZE];


    cufftExecC2C(plan[0],data[0],data[0],CUFFT_FORWARD);

}


int main()
{
   ...
   kernel1<<<N,N>>>(...);
   ...
}
```

I'm calling cufft functions from my kernel function "kernel1". Can I declare variables of type cufftComplex inside kernel.?

Comment: What is the `cufftExecC2C` call doing inside the kernel?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270433/is-it-possible-to-call-cufft-library-calls-in-device-function/17273394#17273394)

Comment: @talonmies that is a function which is provided in CUFFT library

Comment: @user2281757: I know what it is. I am asking *why* you have a host library function call inside a CUDA kernel. That is not allowed.

Comment: @talonmies would you mind posting a brief answer to this effect?  I would appreciate it and would upvote it, so the question can be declared "answered".  Or if you prefer I will mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem using the `cufftComplex` type in CUDA kernel code. `cufftComplex` is just an alias of the standard CUDA single precision complex type `cuComplex`, which is specifically intended for use in device code.

However, the rest of the code in your question is completely wrong. The cuFFT library is a host side library which cannot be called inside CUDA kernel code. So trying to call `cufftExecC2C` inside a kernel is completely illegal and won't compile if you try.

Comment: Is there any way to use cufft library inside a kernel.?

Comment: @user2281757: No there is not.